# How to find the vectorized difference between two lists?

Tags: r

Consider

```
x <- c(1,2,3)
y <- c(1,0,3)
x == y
[1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

I would like to achieve the same result using lists:

```
x <- list(c(11,11) ,c(22,22), c(33,33) )
y <- list(c(11,11) ,c(21,22), c(33,33) )
x == y
```

But instead of
`[1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE`
this gives the error message:

`Error in x == y : comparison of these types is not implemented`

How to find the vectorized difference between two lists?

Performance must be considered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We could use `Map/mapply` to loop over the corresponding elements

```
mapply(setequal, x, y)
[1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

---

Or with `==` and `all`

```
mapply(\(u, v) all(u == v, na.rm = TRUE), x, y)
[1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

---

For a vectorized option (assuming if the lengths are same), then `unlist` the elements, do the `==`, convert to `matrix` and get the `rowSums` of logical matrix

```
rowSums(matrix(unlist(x) == unlist(y), nrow = length(x), byrow = TRUE)) == 2
[1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

Or a variation of the above

```
rowSums(do.call(rbind, x) == do.call(rbind, y)) == 2
[1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

#### Benchmarks

```
> x1 <- rep(x, 1e6)
> y1 <- rep(y, 1e6)
> system.time(mapply(setequal, x1, y1))
   user  system elapsed 
 14.450   0.125  15.013 
> system.time(mapply(\(u, v) all(u == v, na.rm = TRUE), x1, y1))
   user  system elapsed 
  3.535   0.020   3.550 
> system.time(rowSums(matrix(unlist(x1) == unlist(y1),
    nrow = length(x1), byrow = TRUE)) == 2)
   user  system elapsed 
  0.268   0.038   0.307 
> system.time(rowSums(do.call(rbind, x1) == do.call(rbind, y1)) == 2)
   user  system elapsed 
  5.176   0.321   5.524 
> system.time({
   out <- logical(length(x1))
   for(i in seq_along(x1)) {
    out[i] <- all(x1[[i]] == y1[[i]], na.rm = TRUE)
    }
 })
   user  system elapsed 
  1.189   0.055   1.242 
  # base comparison with vectors
> system.time( seq(1e6) == seq(1e6))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.004   0.001   0.006
```

Comment: This is very useful. It would be nice to include seq(1e6) == seq(1e6) in the benchmarks as a base level. The first two solutions are more general. They do not expect equal list size.

Comment: The constant 2 in the rowSums solution should  be `length(x[[1]]).` Otherwise it won't work for `x <- list(c(11) ,c(22), c(33) ), y <- list(c(11) ,c(21), c(33) ).`

Comment: What I am trying to achieve is an outer-join and filter at the same time. I try to keep the required assumptions as small as possible. Therefore, I want to limit myself to basic R. Another assumption I forgot to mention.